# HTML button input position is off in Chrome when value is defined

Tags: html, google-chrome, button, position

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k971hq6q/5/) works as desired in IE 11, but in Chrome the second button is positioned lower than it should be. I've found that all I need to do to reproduce the problem is to set a value in the second button. How to fix?

```
<input style="width:42px; height: 42px" type="button" />
<input style="width:42px; height: 42px" type="button" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the vertical-align property to top:

```
input[type=button] {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k971hq6q/7/)**

The default vertical-align value for inline elements is [baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).